# Reactor - Overflow Strategy IGNORE vs ERROR

Tags: project-reactor

What is the significance of these 2 below overflow strategy? Exceptions are different. But in both cases when subscribers can not keep up, they are notified with an error call.
In which case we should choose one over the other!

```
    FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.ERROR
    FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.IGNORE
```

I found this from the documentation. But does not provide more info.

- IGNORE to Completely ignore downstream backpressure requests. This may yield IllegalStateException when queues get full downstream.
- ERROR to signal an IllegalStateException when the downstream can’t keep up.

`downstream cannot keep up` sounds a lot like `queue gets full` - so for me both look same.

Answer (score 0):

`IGNORE` will ignore the requests from the downstream and simply push the items.
`ERROR` will check the request and fail if there is not enough demand.

Comment: This does not clarify at all. do you have any code samples with explanation

Comment: the difference is subtle: some operators like `flatMap` could have a small capacity to store extraneous elements when overproducing. with `IGNORE` they would have a chance at "recovering" if their consumer only briefly fails to keep up, but THEY would still rapidly propagate an error otherwise. whereas with `ERROR`, it's a hard stop in any case as soon as one element comes in that wasn't requested.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the clarification